# (Add value to number in place) How + operator work in java?

Tags: java

I want to know how + operator work in java, imagine following situation:

```
Long number1 = 5L;
Long number2 = 10L;
Long number3 = number1 + number2;
```

Does the third statement create another `Object` which contain sum of `number1` and `number2`? if so wouldn't be better to have method like `number1.addValue(number2)` to add number2 to number1 in place and don't create new Object?

Comment: You can do that this way `number1 = number1 + number2;` Why need extra method for that ?

Comment: I think something that you write create new Object and put its reference in number1 either, doesn't it?

Comment: You don't need to create it explicitly, Long is immutable, you can try `AtomicInteger` for mutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the third statement create another Object which contain sum of number1 and number2?

Yes it does.

> Wouldn't be better to have method like number1.addValue(number2) to add number2 to number1 in place and don't create new Object?

No it wouldn't.  That would require Java's primitive wrapper classes to be mutable.  In fact, they are immutable.

Consider this:

```
Long five = 5L;
Long ten = 10L
Long sum = five;
sum.addValue(ten);    // Hypothetically ....
```

Question: What is the value of `five` now?

Answer: `five` would now have value `15` ... because `five` and `sum` are the same object.

If they had designed the wrapper classes `Long` and so on to be mutable, then using boxing and unboxing would be a lot more complicated for the programmer.

It is bad enough that the current semantics of `==` for wrapper classes are counter-intuitive.  For example:

```
Long one_million = 1,000,000L;
Long one_million_and_one = one_million + 1L;
Long one_million_again = one_million_and_one - 1L;

System.out.println(one_million.equals(one_million_again));
System.out.println(one_million == one_million_again);
```

... prints `true` and `false`.